# Refresh value HTML element

Tags: button, sencha-touch-2, listitem

I need to some technology of "updatepanel of ASP.net" in sencha touch. The need can be explained like that, I have like button in my page and the counter of the likes. When other client like that item also, I want like count to be incremented automatically, like in the way Facebook.

How can I supply this kind of need? Has anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. A like button that displays the number of like :

http://www.senchafiddle.com/#Cc891

It basically uses the `data` and `tpl` config of `Ext.Button`

Hope this helps

Comment: thank you for quick response, i achive the same result with you in my implementation. however what i want is that. 2 clients run this page, when first one likes and increments the count, can second one see the same incremented number without refreshing the page?

Comment: When a user likes something (let's say a picutre), you send a request to your server that stores the number of like of this picture. Then the other client needs to check with the server for latest likes at regular intervals.

Comment: So retrieving data from server is a must for this situation, thank you for your help.